# Giant gravestones in Forbidden Woods

Tags: bloodborne

So, I've always wondered why there were giant gravestones in the forbidden woods. It would suggest giant graves, but I've never come across anything big enough to warrant such enormous gravestones.

Is there any lore to explain their presence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some digging, I still haven't found anything *concrete*, however, there are some factors that can connect some dots:

The Shadow of Yharnam Boss is located in the "Forbidden Grave" (this is the name of the Lantern that appears once you defeat the Boss). These enemies can also be found in the Nightmare of Mensis, as well as in the Chalice Dungeons; and as their name suggests, they are servants of Queen Yharnam - which ties them to the Pthumerians.

Additionally, we do know that the Pthumerians were the [Guardians of the slumbering Great Ones](https://bloodborne.fandom.com/wiki/Great_Pthumeru_Ihyll_Chalice):

> This reveals that while early Pthumerians were mere humble guardians of the slumbering Great Ones, their descendants felt entitled to name themselves a leader.

So what this could imply is that the Forbidden Grave, and by extension, the Forbidden Woods, are a Mass Grave for the Great Ones, making the Gravestones markers for the Graves of Great Ones, potentially killed by other Hunters, or other Great Ones over the unknown ages past.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing lore-wise about those gravestones. I believe there are a few kneeling corpses in front of some of them, so the most likely explanation is that they mark graves for important people.